# Easy property of projection operators

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, proof-verification

Quick sanity check:

If $V$ is a finite-dimensional $K$-vector space and $\pi:V \to V$ is a projection (i.e. an idempotent $K$-linear map), then $\text{tr}(\pi)=\dim_K (\text{im}(\pi)).$

Proof: As $\pi$ is a projection, we have $V=\ker(\pi)\oplus\text{im}(\pi).$ Take a bases for $\ker(\pi)$ and $\text{im}(\pi).$ The basis resulting from the concatenation of these two bases is an eigenbasis where the basis elements for $\ker(\pi)$ each have eigenvalue $0$ and the basis elements in $\text{im}(\pi)$ each have eigenvalue $1$. Hence the trace, as the sum of these eigenvalues, is exactly $\dim_K (\text{im}(\pi)).$

Is this right?

Many thanks!

Comment: Your proof is correct. Both subspaces in the direct sum are invariant under $V$. $\pi$ is $0$ on one of them and $I$ on the other.